# Delphi Display Records

Tags: delphi

I was able to create a file called speeding.dat to record information about fines registered by a police speed camera. With information such as date, vehicle number, speed, and fine owing. However i am not sure how to develop a subroutine that can query the file by prompting the user to enter the vehicle registration number and display all data in that record.

This is what i have so far..

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;
      type
    Tfine = Record
      name : string[15];
      money : String[15];
      date : String[15];
      speed : String[15];
      registration : string[15];
  end;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  myFile   : File of Tfine;
  policeCamera : Tfine;
begin
  AssignFile(myFile, 'speeding.dat');
  ReWrite(myFile);

  policeCamera.name := 'aaa';
  policeCamera.money  := '299.99';
  policeCamera.registration := '123SPY';
  policeCamera.speed := '140';
  policeCamera.Date := '12/01/2001';
    Write(myFile,policeCamera);

  policeCamera.name := 'bbb';
  policeCamera.money  := '299.99';
  policeCamera.registration := 'HELLA';
  policeCamera.speed := '135';
  policeCamera.Date := '12/01/2002';
    Write(myFile,policeCamera);

  policeCamera.name := 'ccc';
  policeCamera.money  := '299.97';
  policeCamera.registration := 'HELLI';
  policeCamera.speed := '145';
  policeCamera.Date := '12/01/2003';
    Write(myFile,policeCamera);

  policeCamera.name := 'ddd';
  policeCamera.money  := '299.96';
  policeCamera.registration := 'HELLL';
  policeCamera.speed := '200';
  policeCamera.Date := '12/01/2004';
    Write(myFile,policeCamera);

  policeCamera.name := 'eee';
  policeCamera.money  := '399.95';
  policeCamera.registration := 'HELLP';
  policeCamera.speed := '310';
  policeCamera.Date := '12/01/2005';
    Write(myFile,policeCamera);

  policeCamera.name := 'fff';
  policeCamera.money  := '199.94';
  policeCamera.registration := 'HELLT';
  policeCamera.speed := '70';
  policeCamera.Date := '12/01/2006';
  Write(myFile,policeCamera);

  CloseFile(myFile);
end;

end.
```

Comment: So far, you have *nothing* toward your goal. What problem are you having?

Comment: So i made a main form where i stored the records and made a button which takes you to another form where you can search for the Registration number. I am not sure how to connect the records in the main form to the form to the form where i can search.

Comment: First you did not show us what you try , second you can use `TStringGrid` to display your data after you search in your file with `While` loop.that was a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to search for `records` by the vehicle registration number and display it , try this:

```
Var List : TStringGrid; I : Integer;
    myFile   : File of Tfine;
    policeCamera : Tfine;
    Search : String[15];
begin
List := FindComponent('List') as TStringGrid;
List.Free;
Search := InputBox('Type the registration number:' , 'Search' , '');
 List := TStringGrid.Create(Self);
 With List do
  begin
    Align := alLeft;
    Name := 'List';
    Width := 120*5+20;
    FixedCols :=0;
    FixedRows := 1;
    DefaultColWidth := 120;
    ColCount := 5;
    Parent := Self;
  end;

  List.Cells [0,0] := 'Name';
  List.Cells [1,0] := 'Money';
  List.Cells [2,0] := 'Registration';
  List.Cells [3,0] := 'Speed';
  List.Cells [4,0] := 'Date';
  i := 1;
  AssignFile(myFile , 'speeding.dat');
  Reset(myFile);
  While FilePos(myFile) <> FileSize(myFile) do
    begin
      Read(myFile,policeCamera);
     if policeCamera.registration = Search then
      begin
        List.Cells[0,i] := policeCamera.name;
        List.Cells[1,i] := policeCamera.money;
        List.Cells[2,i] := policeCamera.date;
        List.Cells[3,i] := policeCamera.speed;
        List.Cells[4,i] := policeCamera.registration;
        Inc(i);
      end;
    end;
CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

Comment: Thank You so much, i was able to make understanding of what you did and use it for 3 other questions that i was having trouble with.